# program that will take file from user interface .selects directory then it will open all the files in that dir and its sub dir soon

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the code

```
import os
import time
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
Tkinter.Button(subframe, text = "Browse", command = self.loadtemplate, width = 10).pack()
def loadtemplate(self):
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "Desktop",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("text files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
    counts = dict()
    t1 = time.time()
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            words=line.lower()
            words = words.split()
            last_pos = f.tell()
            last_pos = last_pos 
            print last_pos
            for word in words:
                    if word not in counts:
                        counts[word] = 1
                    else:
                        counts[word] += 1
con=True
while con:
    find=raw_input("Enter word to be searched")

    if find in counts:
        print find, " occurs", counts[find]
    else:
        print "not found:"

    inc=raw_input("Want to continue y/n:")
    if inc=='y':
        con=True
    else :
        con=False
```

Comment: And your question is..?

Comment: Your question doesn't include a question.

Answer (score 0):

You have already imported `os` now you can use `os.listdir()` to get contents of the directory you want to access. Continuous loops will help you perform the task.